# Can I replace DDR2 with DDR3?

Tags: memory

My OLD HP MB supports DDR2 667 RAM (only 4 GB now) - Win 7 32 Bit - - - - My newer Win 10 64 Bit HP Burnt The Heck Up  It "used" DDR PC3 Knowing only faster RAM will not speed up my system - Can the present OLD MB handle this added or replacing the OLD DDR2?

Comment: Are you asking if your old laptop will handle windows 10 64 bit?

Comment: The pin placement is different between each iteration of DDR memory. Unless the motherboard supports both DDR2 and DDR3, upgrading to DDR3 will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace DDR2 with DDR3. They are 'similar' form factors but the physical pin out and electrical properties are different.

There's also a reasonable chance that a machine old enough to still use DDR2 may not support more ram, and depending on the configuration, you'd need to scrounge up higher capasity sticks of DDR2 rather than just adding on.